# Removing extension type from a filename

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove extension of a file name. For example:

```
Demo.csv --> Demo
thermal.jpg --> thermal
```

I have used following regex but its not working.

```
/(.*)[^.]+$/
```

Kindly help, thanks in advance!

Comment: `str.replace(/\..*/, '')`

Comment: Use [`name = str.replace(/\.[^.]*?$/, '');`](https://regex101.com/r/mQ6dH7/1)

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following RegExp:

```
/.+\.([^.]+)$/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str='thermal.jpg.png'; // double extension to test behavior

var name=str.substr(0,str.lastIndexOf('.'));  // -> thermal.jpg

    name=str.substr(0,str.indexOf('.'));      // -> thermal
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey thanks to all folks for your help!!!
but this is the RegEXP which I got which is working in my scenario

```
^(.*\.)[^.]+$
```